# Python - Math Operatives (Class, Functions) How to create a class with functions and incorporate Math

Tags: python, function, class

I wanted to create a class with a specific user defined function for each math operative and then print an example with results. I am obviously missing something here and was hoping someone could provide some insight. Thank you,

```
class Math:
   def add(self, x, y):
       return(x + y)
   
   def subtract(self, x, y):
        return(x - y)
    
   def multiply(self, x, y):
        return(x * y)
    
   def divide(self, x, y):
        return(x / y)


print(divide(5, 5))
```

Comment: These functions already exist in stdlib [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module, so you may as well just use them.

Comment: You have to create an instance of the class. `m = Math()` then `m.divide(5, 5)`

Comment: Read a tutorial on OOP in Python to learn the basics.

Comment: The facetious answer is _don't_. This isn't a good use case for a class. A good next step would be to read up on what classes and objects are, and how they're properly used to model programs.

Comment: Not facetious at all, using a class here makes no sense. What you have should just be pure functions.

Answer (score 1):

Because you've defined these functions under your class definition of `Math`, you need an instance of the `Math` class in order to call these functions.

```
math_obj = Math()
print(math_obj.divide(5, 5))
```

If you want that example to run as soon as the class is instantiated, you need to define an `__init__` function, which runs whenever an object of that class is created. Note that the function is still attached to the class, so within a class, you use the `self` variable.

```
class Math:
   
   def __init__(self):
       print(self.divide(5, 5))  
          
   def add(self, x, y):
       return(x + y)
   
   def subtract(self, x, y):
        return(x - y)
    
   def multiply (self, x, y):
        return(x * y)
    
   def divide (self, x, y):
        return(x / y)
```